# Swift add a button that deletes row from list that uses a foreach loop

Tags: swift, foreach, swiftui

I have a list that has a foreach loop and in every row I want to make a delete button that deletes the row.

I have an array of structs

```
struct Lists{
    var title : String
    var id = UUID()
}
```

and the array

```
@State var list = [Lists]()
```

and this is the list

```
List{        
      ForEach(list, id : \.id ){ item in
          NavigationLink(destination:DetailView(word:item.title)){
              HStack {
                 Text(item.title)
                 Spacer()
                 Button(action: {
                      self.list.remove(at: 0)
                 }){
                      Text("×")
                 }
              }
          }
      }
  }
```

I have set the `remove(at:0)` zero because I don't know how to get the index in the for loop.

The list:

[image: the list]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually think is easier to use a count number instead.. like this:

```
List {
      ForEach(0..<list.count, id : \.self ){ index in
        NavigationLink(destination:DetailView(word: list[index].title)){
            HStack {
               Text(list[index].title)
               Spacer()
               Button(action: {
                    self.list.remove(at: index)
               }){
                    Text("×")
               }
            }
        }
      }
   }
```

Comment: Is this less efficient or something? I thought i read somewhere that this is not as good

Comment: Maybe, because of array checking twice. But I Don't think it impacts that much.